# What is the long run variance?

Tags: time-series, variance, references, kernel-smoothing, independence

How is long run variance in the realm of time series analysis defined?

I understand it is utilized in the case there is a correlation structure in the data. So our stochastic process would not be a family of $X_1, X_2 \dots$ i.i.d. random variables but rather only identically distributed?

Could I have a standard reference as an introduction to the concept and the difficulties involved in its estimation?

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154070/where-is-the-dominated-convergence-theorem-being-used/273021#273021

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a measure of the standard error of the sample mean when there is serial dependence.

If $Y_t$ is covariance stationary with $E(Y_t)=\mu$ and $Cov(Y_t,Y_{t-j})=\gamma_j$ (in an iid setting, this quantity would be zero!) such that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty|\gamma_j|<\infty$. Then
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\{Var[\sqrt{T}(\bar{Y}_T- \mu)]\}=\lim_{T\to\infty}\{TE(\bar{Y}_T- \mu)^2\}=\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty\gamma_j=\gamma_0+2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\gamma_j,$$
where the first equality is definitional, the [second a bit more tricky to establish](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154070/where-is-the-dominated-convergence-theorem-being-used) and the third a consequence of stationarity, which implies that $\gamma_j=\gamma_{-j}$.

So the problem is indeed lack of independence. To see this more clearly, write the variance of the sample mean as
\begin{align*}
E(\bar{Y}_T- \mu)^2&=E\left[(1/T)\sum_{t=1}^T(Y_t- \mu)\right]^2\\
&=1/T^2E[\{(Y_1- \mu)+(Y_2- \mu)+\ldots+(Y_T- \mu)\}\\
&\quad\{(Y_1- \mu)+(Y_2- \mu)+\ldots+(Y_T- \mu)\}]\\
&=1/T^2\{[\gamma_0+\gamma_1+\ldots+\gamma_{T-1}]+[\gamma_1+\gamma_0+\gamma_1+\ldots+\gamma_{T-2}]\\
&\quad+\ldots+[\gamma_{T-1}+\gamma_{T-2}+\ldots+\gamma_1+\gamma_0]\}
\end{align*}

A problem with estimating the long-run variance is that we of course do not observe all autocovariances with finite data. Kernel (in econometrics, "Newey-West" or HAC estimators) are used to this end,

$$
\hat{J_T}\equiv\hat{\gamma}_0+2\sum_{j=1}^{T-1}k\left(\frac{j}{\ell_T}\right)\hat{\gamma}_j
$$
$k$ is a kernel or weighting function, the $\hat\gamma_j$ are sample autocovariances. $k$, among other things must be symmetric and have $k(0)=1$. $\ell_T$ is a bandwidth parameter.

A popular kernel is the Bartlett kernel
$$k\left(\frac{j}{\ell_T}\right) = \begin{cases}
\bigl(1 - \frac{j}{\ell_T}\bigr)
\qquad &\mbox{for} \qquad 0 \leqslant j \leqslant \ell_T-1 \\
0 &\mbox{for} \qquad j > \ell_T-1
\end{cases}
$$
Good textbook references are [Hamilton, Time Series Analysis](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/5386.html) or [Fuller](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471552399.html). A seminal (but technical) journal article is [Newey and West, Econometrica 1987](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~kwest/publications/1980/A%20Simple%20PSD%20HAC%20Covariance%20Matrix.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! I checked Time series Analysis by Hamilton. It does in fact say that a non-parametric way to estimate the spectrum is to take a weighted average of the sample covariances but It does not delve into the mathematics behind the determination of this statement. Could you suggest a reference book or paper that explains why is this a good estimator when the sample size increases?

Comment: good point. Made some edits

Comment: It perhaps worth mentioning that the second ("tricky") step requires dominated convergence (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154070/where-is-the-dominated-convergence-theorem-being-used ).

Comment: @TamasFerenci, thanks for the pointer, I included the link.

Comment: @Cristoph Hanck, you're welcome, thanks for the update!

Comment: I think the reason that the long run variance equals $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\{Var[\sqrt{T} (\bar{Y}_T - \mu)]\}$ is because of the central limit theorem (CLT).  By CLT , for random samples $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $\cdots$, $Y_T$ with finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, random variable $Z = \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{\bar{Y}_T - \mu}{\sigma_{\bar{Y}}}\right)$ is a standard normal distribution, where $\sigma_{\bar{Y}} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{T}}$ is the standard error of sample mean. Hence $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\{\sqrt{T} (\bar{Y}_T - \mu)\}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: Hi Christoph, Does CLT hold for random variables with serial dependence?? Does CLT only hold for iid random variables?

Comment: Yes, there are versions of the CLT under serial dependence.