# Is it possible for long-run variance to be negative or 0?

Tags: time-series, variance

I read that "strictly stationary implies that long-run variance is finite and positive", which means that long-run variance can be 0 or negative. However, according to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153444/what-is-the-long-run-variance), it seems that long-run variance can not be negative.

So is it possible for long-run variance to be negative or 0?

Comment: Are you sure that it does not imply that the **long-run variance is *infinite* and positive?**

Comment: A constant time series is strictly stationary with long-run variance zero.  Therefore--by pure logic--it *is* possible for it to be negative or zero.

Comment: @whuber you answered the question if the long-run variance can be 0, but you didn't answer if it can be negative. Linguistic pragmatism precedes pure logic in human interactions

Answer (score 3):

> strictly stationary implies that long-run variance is finite and positive

No, that isn't true. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_t$ be iid Cauchy random variables. None of these even have a variance (or mean). Yet the process is stationary.

> which means that long-run variance can be 0 or negative

No variance can ever be negative, because for any random variable $Y$, $(Y-E[Y])^2 \ge 0$ with probability $1$, then its expectation must be non-negative.

Under typical assumptions, it's strictly positive, too. If you look at the formula from the link you posted, 
$$
\lim_{T\to \infty}\text{Var}[\sqrt{T}(\bar{X}_T - \mu)] = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \gamma(i)
$$
you might not be able to tell right away because a lot of those terms in the sum might be negative. However, recall that autocovariance functions $\gamma(\cdot)$ are *positive definite*. So that term has to be positive. The only thing you have to worry about is whether it's $\infty$ or not. But that is usually taken care of by the assumption of *absolute summability*, or that $\sum_i |\gamma(i)| < \infty$. Finiteness of this implies finiteness of the other.

> So is it possible for long-run variance to be negative or 0?

A stationary process can have a long-run variance of $0$, sure. Take a random sample from a distribution that only has probability on $\mu$. Then $\text{Var}(\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \mu) = 0$ which means its limit is $0$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the popular equation Var(X)=E[X²]-E[X]² then the well-known numerical instabilities *can* cause the result to be negative if E[x] is larger than the standard deviation. But then the result is clearly bad, because **variance is never negative**, and negative values cause the standard deviation to be undefined.

While this equation is found in many many textbooks and papers (and is undoubtedly mathematically correct), it is all but *reliable* with finite *floating* point numbers as used in computers. So it is okay to use this in proofs, but not in code.

Comment: If numerical instabilities can cause the result to be negative, when why "the result is clearly bad"?

Comment: @Aqqq because it’s negative.

Comment: What exactly is numerical instabilities? Is it something opposite to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability? If yes: how does that result in the variance to be negative?

Comment: The exact reason is catastrophic cancellation. You subtract two values of similar magnitude, and all the first bits are the same, and *rounding errors* become relatively big. If you round down the first, round up the second, it can become negative.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that long-run variance is a limit, so it is a little bit different than what one regularly thinks of as variance. For simplicity lets assume $\mu=0$

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\{\text{Var}[\sqrt{T}\bar{Y}_T]\}=\lim_{T\to\infty}\left\{\text{Var}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\left(\sum_i^T Y_i\right)\right]\right\}.$$

Let $Y$ follow a MA(1) process such that
\begin{align}Y_1&=Z_1-Z_0 \;\;\;\;\; Z_i\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)\\ Y_t&=Z_t-Z_{t-1}\end{align}
this leads to
$$\text{Var}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\sum_{i}^TY_i\right]=\text{Var}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}(Z_0+Z_T)\right]=\frac{2}{T} $$

which in the limit approaches 0.