# Derivation of Newey West Formula for Estimating the HAC Covariance Matrix

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, neweywest

I currently reading Whitney Newey and Kenneth West's paper "a simple, positive semidefinite, heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation consistent covariance matrix"

For a multi-regression linear model:
\begin{equation}
y_t = X_t \beta_t + e_t, \qquad t=1,\cdots, T
\end{equation}
where $y_t$ and $X_t$ are given, $\beta_t$ is a non-random but unobservable vector, $e_t$ is the noise term.

According to the paper, the noise covariance of $e_t$, $S_T$ can be estimated using sample errors $\hat{e}_t := y_t - X_t \hat{\beta}_t$, such that
\begin{equation}
\hat{S}_T = \hat{\Omega}_0 + \sum_{j=1}^m w_j\left[\hat{\Omega}_j \hat{\Omega}_j^\top\right],
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\hat{\Omega}_j := \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=j+1}^T\hat{e}_t\hat{e}_{t-j}^\top.
\end{equation}
Can anyone explain to me the derivation of $\hat{S}_T$? Why $\hat{S}_T$ can be expressed as sum of the covariance matrices with different lags?

my first guess is that $e_t$ might follow MA(m) process, such that
\begin{equation}
e_t:= \hat{e}_t + \phi_1\hat{e}_{t-1} + \cdots + \phi_m\hat{e}_{t-m}
\end{equation}
but traditionally for MA(m) process, we assume $\mathbb{E}\{e_{t} e_{t-j}^\top\} = 0$ for nonzero lag $j$.

If we assume that $\mathbb{E}\{\hat{e}_{t} \hat{e}_{t-j}^\top\} \neq 0$ for all $j$, then $e_t$ more like a AR(m) process, hence the covariance matrix is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{e_te_t^\top\} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \phi_1 & \cdots & \phi_m\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \hat{\Omega}_0 & \hat{\Omega}_1 & \cdots & \hat{\Omega}_m \\
\hat{\Omega}_1 & \hat{\Omega}_0 & \cdots & \hat{\Omega}_{m-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\hat{\Omega}_m & \hat{\Omega}_{m-1} & \cdots & \hat{\Omega}_0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \phi_1 \\ \vdots \\ \phi_m\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153444/what-is-the-long-run-variance/153543#153543

Comment: Thank you very much Christoph! it explains a lot. I have one more question, for the sample mean $\bar{Y}_T$, as T approches infinity, does  $\bar{Y}_T$ equals expectation of $Y_t$ equals $\mu$?

Comment: Yes, provided what is known in time series analysis as (mean) ergodicity holds, so basically  a law of large numbers.

Comment: Thank you, but if $\bar{Y}_T \rightarrow \mu$ as $T\rightarrow \infty$, why $\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \{T\mathbb{E}(\bar{Y}_T - \mu)\}$ not equals to zero?

Comment: you are overlooking a square

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put square sign, but the point I confused is that as $T\rightarrow \infty$, should $\bar{Y}_T - \mu = 0$?

Comment: Yes, the sample mean converges to the expected value, but this is not what my link discusses (although that result over there implies consistency of the sample mean).