# Arima simulation followed by modeling in R produces bad estimates

Tags: r, time-series, arima, moving-average

Simulate a moving average using `arima.sim` in `R`.  Then estimate the coefficients using `arima`.  Fix all coefficients to their true values, except one:

```
set.seed(222)
x <- arima.sim(model = list(ma=c(1, 0, 0, -0.8)), n = 500, rand.gen = rnorm)
arima(x,order = c(0,0,4), fixed = c(1, 0, 0, NA, 0), method = "ML")
```

Results:

```
Call:
arima(x = x, order = c(0, 0, 4), fixed = c(1, 0, 0, NA, 0), method = "ML")

Coefficients:
      ma1  ma2  ma3      ma4  intercept
        1    0    0  -3.6772          0
s.e.    0    0    0   0.2970          0

sigma^2 estimated as 0.159:  log likelihood = -901.13,  aic = 1806.26
```

I expect the estimate of ma4 to be close to $-0.8$, but get $-3.68$.  Why is the parameter estimate so far from the true parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's more than one way to parameterize MA models.  Your parameterization disagrees with the one used by the software.

---

Your model for the time series process $(Y_t)$ is

$$(Y_t - \mu) = (1 + \theta_1 L + \theta_2 L^2 + \theta_3 L^3 + \theta_4 L^4)\, \varepsilon_t$$

where $\mu=0$ is the mean, $L$ is the lag operator, the $\epsilon_t$ are white noise, and the parameters are $(\theta_i) = (1,0,0,-0.8).$

The four roots $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_4$ of the associated polynomial $1 + \theta_1 z + \cdots + \theta_4 z^4 = 1 + z - 0.8 z^4$ are $-0.7486682, -0.2769154 \pm 1.09781i,$ and $1.3024989.$  Because they are not all outside the unit circle (the first one has a norm less than $1$), this process is not [invertible.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50682/what-is-the-intuition-of-invertible-process-in-time-series)

**There is an invertible process with exactly the same statistical properties,** obtained by using the reciprocals of the roots inside the unit circle and rescaling the polynomial to have a constant term of $1.$ That replaces $-0.7486682$ by $-1.3357052$ and the associated polynomial becomes

$$\eqalign{
&(z - (-1.3357))(z - (-0.2769 + 1.0978i))((z - (-0.2769 - 1.0978i))(z - 1.3024) \\
&\propto 1 + 0.41296 z + 0.19707 z^2 - 0.26322 z^3 - 0.4484 z^4,
}$$

corresponding to the model

$$(Y_t - \mu) = (1 + 0.41296 L + 0.19707 L^2 - 0.26322 L^3 - 0.4484 L^4)\, \delta_t.$$

(The *fundamental innovations* $\delta_t$ are a constant multiple of the original white noise process $\varepsilon_t.$)

**Because the software assumes the process is invertible, *these* are the coefficients it estimates.**  Indeed, when you don't constrain the estimates

```
> arima(x, order = c(0,0,r), method = "ML")
```

the output includes

> ```
> Coefficients:
>          ma1     ma2      ma3      ma4  intercept
>       0.4238  0.1429  -0.2699  -0.4662     0.0173
> s.e.  0.0402  0.0437   0.0449   0.0408     0.0493
> ```

and you can observe a close match of all estimates with the invertible coefficients (within $1.25$ times the standard errors in this case).

---

**The solution to your quandary is to solve this exercise by proposing coefficients of an invertible model in the first place.**  You don't have to find polynomial roots to do that: simply pick $k$ numbers $\lambda_i$ of (complex) modulus no less than $1$ for the roots, construct the polynomial $$p(z) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^k (z-\lambda_i) }{ \prod_{i=1}^k (-\lambda_i)} = 1 + p_1 z + p_2 z^2 + \cdots + p_k z^k,$$  and specify the vector $(p_1,p_2, \ldots, p_k)$ in the simulation.

Here's an example in `R` with $(\lambda_i)=(1,3/2,\pm 2i).$ Because the complex roots occur in conjugate pairs ($\pm 2i$), the model will be real:

```
lambda <- c(1, 3/2, 2i, -2i)
p <- 1; for (l in lambda) p <- convolve(p, c(1, -l), type="open")
(coeff <- Re(p[-1] / p[1]))
```

The coefficients are $(-5/3, 11/12, -5/12, 1/6) \approx (-1.667, 0.917, -0.417, 0.167).$  Now simulate and fit.  (This time let's generate a much longer series so the estimates will be more reliable.)

```
set.seed(17)
x <- arima.sim(model = list(ma=coeff), n = 5000)
arima(x, order = c(0,0,length(coeff)), method = "ML")
```

> ```
> Coefficients:
>           ma1     ma2      ma3     ma4  intercept
>       -1.6536  0.9069  -0.4110  0.1577          0
> s.e.   0.0141  0.0268   0.0265  0.0141          0
>
> sigma^2 estimated as 0.9754:  log likelihood = -7037.65,  aic = 14087.31
> ```

Not only are the coefficients well-estimated, so also is the variance of the innovations $\sigma^2$ (which was equal to $1$ by default).

---

#### Reference

Hamilton, James D. (1994), *Time Series Analysis,* Princeton University Press: Section 3.7, *Invertibility.*