# how does R ensure stationarity and invertibility when fitting an ARIMA model?

Tags: r, arima, stationarity

In the [Forecasting: principles and practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html) book they claim that:

> R ensures the fitted model is both stationary and invertible

I checked and indeed - for example the following model fits, even though the data are not stationary and I should have differenced:

```
library(fpp2)
fit2 <- arima(taylor, order=c(1,0,1), 
        include.mean = TRUE, transform.pars=FALSE)
1/forecast:::arroots(fit2)$roots
autoplot(fit2)
```

and the AR inverse root is `0.9813966+0i`, which is a bad sign according to the text.

but HOW do they do it? When I try fitting the same model with python's `statsmodels` it fails. What's the technique used for ensuring stationarity and invertibility?

Note that `transform.pars=FALSE` so it's not that.

Comment: See my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/432342/919, which includes code for changing a non-invertible MA model into an invertible one.

Comment: thanks! what do you mean by `using the reciprocals of the roots inside the unit circle and rescaling the polynomial to have a constant term of 1`? can you be more specific about what to do and why will it always work

Comment: My answer was *very* specific about that by providing code to carry out the calculations (which is only two lines long!). "Rescaling" means multiplying by a constant, as executed by the line `coeff <- Re(p[-1] / p[1])`.  This multiplies the polynomial $p_0+p_1t + \cdots + p_kt^k$ by $1/p_0$ and drops the constant term (which, since it's $1$ by construction, doesn't need to be carried around).  The reason for taking the real part via `Re` is only to coerce the data type of the coefficients to double-precision numbers; they will already be real numbers.

Comment: @whuber - ok, I now understand the mechanism you suggest for transforming a non-invertible process to an invertible one. I understand that this will preserve the statistical properties of the process (i.e. the mean and the auto-covariance), but won't it be a **different** process than the one we fitted? Won't the residuals be different and the quality of our fit to the data be different?

Comment: Actually not.  The fit and residuals will not differ.  That's why the various versions of the process cannot be distinguished by the data alone.

Comment: @whuber - wow! can you explain why? or would you rather I open a separate question for that?